# Generate Access Token for Simple_Oauth authentication in Drupal 8

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, drupal-8

My motive is to generate an access token for the client (through *simple_oauth* module of Drupal) with the help of which the client can access the content of Drupal 8 site via REST API. But the Generate token tab is not available on the screen, also I have tried generating the token through Postman by using OAuth2.0 authentication, but failed to understand what to write in the Authorization URL and token URL field.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my experience, missing functionality means a missing or disabled module.

Answer (score 0):

[**Quick demo (Password Grant)**](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_oauth)

Install the module using Composer: composer config repositories.drupal composer https://packages.drupal.org/8 && composer require drupal/simple_oauth:^3. You can use any other installation method, as long as you install the OAuth2 Server composer package.

Generate a pair of keys to encrypt the tokens. And store them outside of your document root for security reasons.

```
openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048
openssl rsa -in private.key -pubout > public.key
```

Save the path to your keys in: /admin/config/people/simple_oauth.

Go to REST UI and enable the oauth2 authentication in your resource.

Create a Client Application by going to: /admin/config/services/consumer/add.

Create a token with your credentials by making a POST request to /oauth/token. See the documentation about what fields your request should contain.
(Not shown) Permissions are set to only allow to view nodes via REST with the authenticated user.

Request a node via REST without authentication and watch it fail.

Request a node via REST with the header Authorization: Bearer {YOUR_TOKEN} and watch it succeed.**